# Why does ps aux displays a number instead of a username?

Tags: linux, ps

Running `ps aux` just gave me the following output:

```
...
www-data 26254  0.0  0.7  27304  3544 ?        S    15:07   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1001     25807  0.8  0.8  48444  4332 ?        Sl   Sep03 1330:24 ./ts3server_linux_x86
...
```

**www-data** is the **apach2** user. That's okay, it's what I expected with `-u`, but what is **1001**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that user id is 1001 but that id has no name assigned. This can happen for example a command running in a chroot with a user defined in that chroot will not necessarily have a  name assigned outside the chroot.

Answer (score 24):

This can happen if the username is longer than 8 characters.

Comment: Quote `man ps` under NOTES section: "If the length of the username is greater than the length of the display column, the numeric user ID is displayed instead."

Answer (score 1):

This is most like user's id (uid) for a user which was removed after the process was started.  Or perhaps there was some kind of failure resolving username from uid.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [uid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier_%28Unix%29) for users whose name is unknown (e.g. an uid missing in /etc/passwd) or perhaps with strange spelling (like maybe `Debian-exim`, or a user with a long enough user-name, or for a bad entry in `/etc/passwd`)

Comment: +1 for "long enough"; `ps` has a strange default limit.

Answer (score 0):

It's the user ID. There are cases where Linux doesn't display usernames (this can be a permissions issue). Check out this thread:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ps-aux-displays-users-as-uids-instead-of-username-645456/